# Big Query INSERT INTO with WITH Clause giving error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to insert data into Big Query Table.
My query is complex and involves with clause, it is throwing error for all combinations I can try. I have written similar query in Hive and that works like charm.

Any suggestion on how can I achieve this is higly appreciated:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false \
'with mapping_table as (SELECT t1.a, t2.b, t2.c from table1 as t1 inner join table2 on t2 group by ) 
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my-bq-dev.myschema.mytable PARTITION(CREATE_DT) 
SELECT A, B, C ...... from TABLEX LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEY ON'
```

**Note** the error is not related to syntax as My above query without INSERT OVERWRITE is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

`INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ...` is not BigQuery SQL.

Could you take a look at below example to see how `insert into` works with `WITH` clause?

```sql
create temp table t as select 1 x;

insert into t
with data as (select 2 x)
select * from data;

select * from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my-bq-dev.myschema.mytable PARTITION(CREATE_DT) 

with mapping_table as (SELECT t1.a, t2.b, t2.c from table1 as t1 inner join table2 on t2 group by ) 

SELECT A, B, C ...... from TABLEX LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEY ON
```